# Chinese characters becomes ? in About Me division of profile page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page, encoding

In [my profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/161452/liuyan), all Chinese characters of **About Me** becomes ?.

But in the edit profile page, these Chinese characters are displayed ok.

*Guess* the character encoding is not set properly when displaying **About Me**.

Comment: You could possibly try converting them to unicode html characters [here](http://www.pinyin.info/tools/converter/chars2uninumbers.html).  From the two characters in your username I got - `&#21016;&#30740;`

Comment: [Looks like it's working now](http://i.imgur.com/47MCp.png)... Did you use the unicode representations?

Comment: In the html source they aren't encoded as entities.

Comment: @Lix, yes, I tried [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp), it works, Thanks! However, I wish I can input Chinese characters directly.

Comment: Interesting, I just did a whole sites profile update without using HTML entities, it seems working now. Does stackexchange staffs updated the code?

Comment: It is unlikely that a fix would be pushed within an hour of you reporting this issue... **unlikely but not impossible**...

Comment: According current revision number `rev 2012.7.15.3356`, it seems that the code does not updated. When I regiestred, I tried many times to update profile, but Chinese characters displayed as ? in profile page even if it displayed ok in edit profile page.

Comment: I think this is due to some issue in your browser or a proxy between you and us. There is no reason Unicode characters would not display properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what Jeff said:

> I think this is due to some issue in your browser or a proxy between you and us. There is no reason Unicode characters would not display properly.